Summing specific column from mutliple tables based on location column in PowerBI
I have 3 tables which has same column names but different data. I want to sum product_price data location wise. I can append all three files and can easily retrieve the data but I want try creating a measure and not merging 3 files.
I tried using SUMX but not able to do so because I don't know how to extract data through three file without merging them.


do you want to display in card or in table? it's better to provide some sample data and expected output

@Ryan : Edited the question with desired expected outpout

you can create a dim location table
dim_location =
DISTINCT (
    UNION (
        DISTINCT ( 'Table1 - 2003'[Location] ),
        DISTINCT ( 'Table1 -2002'[Location] ),
        DISTINCT ( 'Table1 - 2003'[Location] )
    )
)

then create relationships with three tables

then create a measure
MEASURE =
SUM ( 'Table1 -2001'[Product Price] ) + SUM ( 'Table1 -2002'[Product Price] )
    + SUM ( 'Table1 - 2003'[Product Price] )



This works !! but when I tried today in my computer I was able to do this without creating the dummy table. But yes all my tables were connected as done by Ryan. May be when I was writing the DAX due to some syntax error I was not able to see other tables.

It would be helpful if you could provide an example of your data for more context. But I believe this what you're trying to achieve.
TotalProductPrice = 
SUMX(Table1, Table1[product_price]) + 
SUMX(Table2, Table2[product_price]) + 
SUMX(Table3, Table3[product_price])


Updated the question
